# Passing SItecore Item ID to Model from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controller, sitecore

I am creating products from a product template.  Each time a customer selects a product to view information about, the data from that product needs to get loaded.  I have created a controller, model and view.  The model is generated with TDS.  I need to pass the item id to the [SitecoreId] from the controller.  Here is the code I am using:

From the layout:

```
@{var id = Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("{74A67488-8E33-47E2-86F5-25AD23FDF3D3}"); }
@Html.Sitecore().ControllerRendering("ProductOverview", "Index", new { ItemId = @id })
```

The controller:

```
public class ProductOverviewController : Controller
{ 
    private readonly IMvcContext _mvcContext;

    public ProductOverviewController(IMvcContext mvcContext)
    {
        _mvcContext = mvcContext;
    }
    // GET: ProductOverview
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var itemId = string.Empty;
        var rc = RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull;
        if (rc != null)
        {
            var parms = rc.Rendering.Properties;
            itemId = parms["ItemId"];
        }

        var dataSource = _mvcContext.GetContextItem<ProductOverviewModel> ();
        return View(dataSource);
    }
}
```

The itemId var has the correct id that I am passing from the layout (hard coded for now).  From here I am at an absolute loss on how to get that into the model.  I have tried dozens of suggestions from searches but the model always uses the current item (as set by GlassBase in the model itself) as opposed to the product id that contains the data for that product.

Is what I want to do even possible?  Can the [SitecoreId] even be overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line where you are setting the value for dataSource using Glass Mapper is where you'll want to make your change..

Glass Mapper lets you use a number of different options to get the Item and cast to your "type" which looks to be ProductOverviewModel currently.

you can use the following for example (notice that I've used .SitecoreService.GetItem instead of .GetContextItem ):

```
 //pass the GUID into here (you'd need to cast to a Guid first instead of ID)
 var dataSource = _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<ProductOverviewModel>(guid);
 //or if you wanted to get your ID as a Sitecore Item you could use
  var dataSource = _mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<ProductOverviewModel>(item.Paths.Path);
```